# jQuery set css position in animate function

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-animate

How would you set the `position:relative` property in an element that does not have an initial `position` property set, within jQuery's `animate()`?

This does not work:

```
$(mLinks[id]).animate
(
    {
        position:'relative',
        left:'200px'
    }
);
```

Given that `mLinks` is a valid DOM element object.

I also tried with the `duration` and `callback` parameters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It does not make sense to "animate" the css `position` attribute isn't it? There is nothing between `relative` and `absolute` or `static` or anything like that...

This is what I would do:

```
$(mLinks[id]).css('position', 'relative').animate
(
    {
        left:'200px'
    }
);
```

If you read the corresponding [jQuery doc](http://api.jquery.com/animate/), you will find this:

`most properties that are non-numeric cannot be animated using basic jQuery functionality (For example, width, height, or left can be animated but background-color cannot be, unless the jQuery.Color() plugin is used).`

Comment: What about `float:`? I know it's non-numerical but what if you don't know the dimensions of an element? Or would you have to determine them through JS first?

Comment: You cannot animate `float` either. I am not sure what you want to do... change the layout gradually? Like, in http://jsfiddle.net/AfFtz/ you want the text to magically go onto the right of the div? Unfortunately jquery isn't that clever.....

Answer (score 2):

The `animate` method don't let you to set css attributes and this make sense, although to have  a great animation you must set correctly the css attributes, these are two different things.

So first you should set the css attribute. And you should use `css` method:

```
$(mLinks[id]).css("position", "relative")
```

After you can start with the animation:

```
$(mLinks[id]).animate({ left:'200px' });
```

Combining all together you'll have:

```
$(mLinks[id]).css("position", "relative").animate({ left:'200px' });
```

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this code.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hello there</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src = "assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="tobechanged" style = "background:#ddd;position:fixed;">
        hello there.
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $('.tobechanged').css('position','relative').animate({
        opacity: 0.9,
        left: '+=50'},
        4000, function() {
        //some stuff here.
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

This now should work just fine.